# Is CBS Radio Mystery Theater in the Public Domain in the US?

Tags: united-states, copyright, public-domain

The Internet Archive says it is but that's just something a user wrote.  I can't find any information on this elsewhere.

Comment: Could one of the close voters please leave a comment explaining what details, clarity, or focus this question lacks?  It seems fine.

Comment: I also don't see any missing details or lack of clarity.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: Probably not.

Per Wikipedia, under USA law, for any audio recordings published after February 15, 1972, the earliest it it will enter public domain is 2043.

CBS Mystery Theater was published from January 6, 1974 through December 31, 1982, per Wikipedia. Therefore, these recordings are not likely to be in the public domain until after 2043.

If CBS, or whichever company now owns CBS Mystery Theater were to have made it available under a sufficiently permissive license, it's likely that it would, in practice, be in a very similar status to being in public domain. However with a quick search, I couldn't find any evidence that the owner of CBS Mystery Theater has in fact done so.

Of course, my searching is imperfect, and Wikipedia might be wrong. It's possible that it is indeed released under a sufficiently permissive license, though I wouldn't personally bet on it. Finally, I'm not a lawyer, so my reading of the whole situation might be really wrong.